# std::auto_ptr error

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

For the below C++ code, I am getting an compiler error:

```
class Mkt
{
    int k;
public:
    Mkt(int n): k(n)
    {
        throw;
    }
    ~Mkt()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nINSIDE Mkt DTOR function:\t"<<endl;
    }
    void func1()
    {
        cout<<"\n\nINSIDE FUNC1 function....value of k is:\t"<<k<<endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    try
    {
        std::auto_ptr<Mkt> obj(new Mkt(10)); //no implicit conversion
            obj.func1(); //error C2039: 'func1' : is not a member of 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>'
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nINSIDE EXCEPTION HANDLER..........."<<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting the error C2039? I am using VS 2008 compiler.

Pls help. 
Thanks

Comment: Why the comment about implicit conversion? You're not requesting an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Kiril-Kirov also, when I am changing my code by introducing Mkt* for auto_ptr as: 'std::auto_ptr<Mkt*> obj(new Mkt(10)); 
  obj->func1();' I am again getting the previous error. I tried to make the function call as: 'obj.func1(); ' but still getting the same error. I am not able to understand this

Comment: @Tomalak-Geretkal yes I was trying to remind myself of the syntax that I am not requesting implicit conversion. That's why the comment (-:

Answer (score 6):

It is `auto_ptr`, this means, that it is pointer :). You must use `operator->`:

```
obj->func1();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `->`

```
obj->func1();
```

`auto_ptr` doesn't have `func1()`, but it has `operator ->()` that will yield a `Mkt*` pointer stored inside and then `->` will be used again on that pointer and this will call the `Mkt::func1()` member function.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that after you fix the compilation problem (change dot-operator into -> operator) you will encounter a huge run-time problem.

```
Mkt(int n): k(n)
{
    throw;
}
```

`throw` without an argument is meant to be used inside catch-blocks and causes re-throwing handled exception. Called outside catch-blocks will result in a call to `abort` function and your program termination.
You probably meant something like

```
throw std::exception();
```

or, better,

```
throw AnExceptionDefinedByYou();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic thing in c++ .. auto_ptr - the "ptr" stands for "pointer",